# Convergence of Roots for an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, roots

Show that the roots of 
$$
f(z) = z^n+z^3+z+2 =0 
$$
converge to the circle $|z|=1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: ...please...? What've you done so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quantity $$g(z) = z^3 + z + 2$$ has no zeros in the open unit disk and $$f_n(z) = z^n + z^3 + z + 2 \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} g(z)$$ uniformly on compact subsets of the open unit disk.  As a consequence we can show that, for any $0 < \epsilon \leq 1$, there is an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that, for $n \geq N$, $f_n(z)$ has no zeros in the disk $|z| \leq 1-\epsilon$.  Thus the accumulation points of the zeros of the polynomials $f_n(z)$, if there are any, must lie in $|z| \geq 1$.

Similarly, $$h_n(z) = z^n f(1/z) \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$$ uniformly on compact subsets of the open unit disk, so we may likewise conclude that any accumulation points of the zeros of the polynomials $h_n(z)$ must lie in $|z| \geq 1$.

Combining these two observations yields the result.

Comment: Nice clean argument. Can you see how to determine which modulus one numbers are actually limit points?

Comment: @julien, There might be a simpler way to do it but I can never resist using a certain sledgehammer [due to Erdős and Turán](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1969500) (see also [Proposition 2.3 here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4110) if you don't have access to the E&T paper).  Essentially if $\sharp_n(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is the number of zeros of $f_n(z)$ in the sector $\theta_1 \leq \arg z < \theta_2$ then $$\left(\frac{\sharp_n(\theta_1,\theta_2)}{n} - \frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{2\pi}\right)^2 < \frac{256 \log\left(5/\sqrt{2}\right)}{n}.$$ (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) So in the limit as $n \to \infty$ the zeros are uniformly radially distributed on the unit circle.

Comment: Very, very nice. I see I've asked a specialist. Thank you very much, +1.

Answer (score 5):

Intuitively, if $|z| \gt 1$, taking a large power will make it *very* large, so much so that the other terms can't bring the sum down to zero.  If $|z| \lt 1$, taking a large power will make it *very* small, so we can ignore it.  Then we need $z=-1$ to be a root of what is left,but that violates what we already said about $z$.

To make this more rigorous, use the triangle inequality.  To have a root, we need $|z|^n=|z^3+z+2|$ and so on.

Comment: I, as well, went through that intuition, but I am not sure this is rigorous enough.  This is a prelim problem and has no sub parts so there must be a lot to consider.  I was thinking of applying Rouche's theorem inside a ball of radius $1-\delta$ and then outside $1+\delta$ and all the roots must be inside.  Is this enough?

Comment: @EagerStudent:  I don't know the standards of writing up prelim problems-I never did them.  But I am sure you can follow this route, there may be others.  Certainly you can say if $|z|=1+\epsilon$ you can find an $n$ for which there are no roots that large in absolute value.  You just need it large enough that $(1+\epsilon)^n \gt 3+\epsilon+(1+\epsilon)^3$.  I'm not seeing the other direction as easily.

Comment: You need $\epsilon_n$, not $\epsilon$, so it is not that obvious, actually.

Comment: @Aryabhata:  I think to rule out $\epsilon$ I get to pick $n$ later and can always pick it large enough.

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at. Care to elaborate? btw, using $\epsilon_n$ can be made to work (and is not difficult), all I am saying is that it is not obvious.

Comment: @Aryabhata:  I am suggesting that to prove a given $|z| \gt 1$ is not a limit point of roots of the equation it suffices to find a small disk around $z$ that has no roots of the equation inside it for large enough $n$.  I get to pick the radius of the disk and the $n$ after $z$ is selected.  So I pick the radius as half the distance to the unit circle.  Then I pick $n$ large enough that the smallest $|z'|^n$ in the disk is greater than $2+|z"^3|+|z'''|$ for $z",z'''$ in the disk.

Comment: I guess that would work, but you also need to show the existence of limit points. EDIT: That is actually shown, by showing $0$ roots in the disk. So I guess you don't need  to explicitly show that...