# Necessary conditions for not having roots

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose $f(z)=\sum_0^\infty  a_n z^n$ has a radius of convergence of $R$. What are necessary conditions, in terms of $\{a_n\}$, for $f(z)=0$ not to have any roots?

Any combinations of real/complex restrictions on coefficients/roots can be assumed.

EDIT:

Does [Weierstrass Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassProductTheorem.html) give any practical answers, that is:

If so then there is $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nz^n$ such that $\displaystyle {f(z)=f(0) e^{g(z)}}$. Now expand right hand side and see if you can get $b$'s out of $a$'s.

Comment: Your addition "Does this works:..." is not true. The proposed relation means only f has no zeroes in some neighbourhood of z=0, no more and no less. BTW, is it fair to make a big edition not indicating the one?

Comment: @user64494 As you say one gets the $b$'s, but radius of convergence is not clear.

Comment: At first glance I wouldn't expect there to be nice necessary conditions.  For example the series $\sum_0^\infty z^k/k!$ and $\sum_0^\infty z^k/(k+1)!$ have almost identical coefficients but latter has infinitely many zeros while the former has none.

Comment: @ Antonio Vargas : You wrote:"...have almost identical coefficients ...".It is not clear in view of $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac {(k+!)!} {k!}=\infty. $$

Comment: @user64494 how does your proposed method (looking at $\log f$) make it clear that $\sum z^k/(k+1)!$ has zeros?

Comment: @ Antonio Vargas: Why don't you understand that the proposed condition is only  necessary? It may be satisfied, but the function under investigation may have zeroes.

Comment: @user64494 are you always so sour?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I saw your thesis on section of power series. I wonder is it true/known that roots of a $n$-section of a rootless $f$, as above, together with poles of $f$ are evenly distributed on $z=R$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: @Maesumi, If I understand what you're asking then I think Jentzsch's theorem is relevant: it says that, given a power series with finite radius of convergence $R$, every point on the circle $|z| = R$ is a limit point of the zeros of the partial sums of the power series.  This happens regardless of whether the limit function has zeros or not.  (cont...)

Comment: (...inued) I believe the question of whether the zeros are evenly distributed has been studied but I can't think of a specific reference.  For that you might be interested in the result of Erdős and Turán that I link in [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371862/convergence-of-roots-for-an-analytic-function/371940#comment798322_371940) which considers general polynomials rather than focusing on partial sums of power series.  By the way, you're welcome to email me at the address listed on my webpage if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the function $$\log(f(z)):=\int_0^z \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)} dw $$ has $R$ less than or equal to the radius of convergence of its Maclaurin series. This produces a necessary condition on $\{a_n\}$.

Comment: It should be $$\log(f(z)):=\int_0^z \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)} dw+\log(f(0)),$$ of course.

Comment: I am looking for general conditions, so $a$'s are not specified. How can this integral lead to conditions on $a$'s.

Comment: We can express the Maclaurin coefficients of g(z):=log(f(z)) in terms of the Maclaurin cofficients of f(z). The formula of [the radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) applied to the Maclaurin series of g(z) produces the necessary condition on {an}. The one is not simple. The standard integral representation of log(f(z)) was written to demonstrate its definition without any branch cuts.

Comment: [The radius of univalence](https://www.google.com.ua/#sclient=psy-ab&q=radius+of+univalence&oq=+radius+of+univalenc&gs_l=hp.1.0.0i30.8731.10363.1.12036.3.3.0.0.0.0.159.464.0j3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.J9ZjvaRi9Mk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.bGE&fp=44c7acaa64a6dd2d&biw=1280&bih=847) is close to this topic and may be useful.